# AutoComplete Intellisense erasing stuff when I hit TAB

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, autocomplete, macros, intellisense

When I start typing a variable name the IntelliSense give a Dropdown with the member list.
[image: Bug1]

Now When I hit TAB this happens, it erases the `if (` and completes the variable name.
[image: Bug2]

This is happening because my **Member List Commit Characters** are : `{}[].,:;+-*/%&|^!=<>?@#\`
**If I inclue `()` the above problem dosent occur**

Notice I have removed the `()`.That is because I have macro `#define pb(x) push_back(x)`.
So whenever I type `vector.pb` and hit the `(` key it would choose `pop_back` (as shown below)

[image: Bug3]

#### So here any one of the following solutions should work :

1. How do i remove `(` as an autocomplete character but not affecting TAB auto completion.
2. How do I get a macro to show up in the drop down member list box.

Comment: I don't have a solution to your problem, but defining macros like these just makes the code harder to read for others. And obviously, it indirectly leads to weird problems like these.

Comment: @VictorSand Oh Dont worry I am just a Competitive Programmer :) So these macros help me solve problems really fast.

Comment: Then I shall worry no more, I see your reasons for trying to fiddle with things. Although I doubt it will save much time instead of just using autocomplete for push_back.

Comment: Use inlined functions. They're just as fast as macro's and cause less parsing problems.